# Swift closure adding more than 2 value

Tags: swift

I am new to swift and especially to closure, when I was practicing sum function  I can add 2 value but when I try to do for 3 or more values I get error

ex:
 adding 2 value which works

```
var calculate: (Double,Double)->Double
calculate = {$0+$1}
print(calculate(4,3))
```

but this one give error

```
var calculate: (Int,Int,Int)->Int

calculate = {$0+$1+$2} 

print(calculate(5,8,90))
```

is there any reason we cannot perform this .. can you suggest me the way to do this using closure

Thanks

Comment: Works for me in Xcode 8.2.1. What is the error message you get?

Comment: Probably "ambiguous reference to member '+'", can reproduce in 8.3.2 Playground.

Comment: I am on Xcode 8.3.2 and error is.   ambiguous reference to member '+'
calculate1 = {$0+$1+$2}
                ^

Comment: Looks like a regression, it compiles in Swift 3.0.2, but not in Swift 3.1 or 4 – you should [file a bug](https://bugs.swift.org).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compiler does not reproduce type of result correctly in this case. You should help it a little:

```
var calculate: (Int,Int,Int) -> Int
calculate = { Int($0+$1+$2) }
print(calculate(5,8,90)) // "103\n"
```

Answer (score 0):

I change your code.

```
var calculate: (Int,Int,Int)->Int

calculate = {($0+$1)+$2} 

print(calculate(5,8,90))
```

-> You need to give round bracket.